# laravel - CSRF token always changes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

Well this is the problem I am facing from yesterday. It is always giving me `TokenMismatchException` and when I digged in and compared a few things, I found that on my local server, the `_token` field never changes. But on my production, it does. And that's the reason it kept giving me `TokenMismatchException`. Does anyone know how to fix this error.

**I have**

1. seen [this question](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/csrf-form-token-doesnt-match-session-token)
2. Went through documentation.
3. Wrote several codeception tests.
4. `<input id="token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` this already in my code.

Comment: [Here is the code](view-source:cornchat.ga/auth/register). Check line number 132. It's always changing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you have `domain` in the `config/session.php` setup to the right path. Even I had got the same problem. And resolved it just by changing that path.

Answer (score 0):

May be usefull.

Html:

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Js:

```
var network = {
    post: function(path, params, cb, type){
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            type: 'post',
            data: params,
            headers: { "X-CSRF-TOKEN" : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
            dataType: type,
            success: function (response, status) {
                if (status == "success") {
                    if (response.reason == "token_timeout") {
                        var new_token = response.new_token;
                        $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content', new_token);
                        network.post(path, params, cb, type);
                    }else{
                        cb(response);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

network.post('path to handler...', { key: value... }, function(response){
   if(response.status == 'success'){
       // to do
   }
}, "json");
```

/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception) {

        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
            return response()->json(['reason' => 'token_timeout', 'new_token' => csrf_token()], 200);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```