# laravel csrf always changes even with cookie domain

Tags: laravel, csrf

session driver changed from **file** to **cookie**

cookie domain added to .env like **example.com**

cookie path in session.php is "/"

but every page refresh I see new CSRF token...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499344/laravel-csrf-token-always-changes

Comment: it's not duplicate... that topic doesn't help

Comment: @PavelProkofiev I've tried this on a fresh install of Laravel using the development server (`php artisan serve`) and can't seem to reproduce your result. I'm dumping the session data to check the token with `dump(session()->all());` and always get the same `_token` value in session. Please offer more details about your setup and how you are evaluating the CSRF token. Are you using a dedicate HTTP server such as nginx or apache, and is so please provide any virtual host configuration files.